# Get Parent Code based on Parent Tag all in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We need to get the Parent CODE based on the Parent TAG from a result set similar to below all in one query or one query with subquery. The TAG field gets added by multiples of 3 (e.g. AAA, AAAAAA, AAAAAB and so one). So the Parent TAG is always the length of the Childs TAG - 3).
We thought maybe a subquery like below but it is returning NULL for every record.

```
Select [Level], [Code], [TAG], LEFT([TAG], LEN([TAG]) -3) AS [Parent TAG], [Parent Code] = CASE WHEN [LEVEL] = 1 THEN NULL ELSE (SELECT [CODE] FROM [MyTable] WHERE [TAG] = LEFT([TAG], LEN([TAG]) -3) END)
FROM [MyTable]
```

Or:

```
Select [Level], [Code], [TAG], LEFT([TAG], LEN([TAG]) -3) AS [Parent TAG], [Parent Code] = CASE WHEN [LEVEL] = 1 THEN NULL ELSE (SELECT [CODE] FROM [MyTable] WHERE [TAG] = [Parent Tag] END)
FROM [MyTable]
```

Data:

```
|Level|Code |Tag      |Parent Tag|Parent Code|
|     |     |         |          |           |
| 1   |1.0  |AAA      |          |           |
| 2   |1.1  |AAAAAA   |AAA       |           |
| 3   |1.1.1|AAAAAAAAA|AAAAAA    |           |  
| 2   |1.2  |AAAAAB   |AAA       |           |
| 3   |1.1.2|AAAAAAAAB|AAAAAB    |           |
| 2   |1.3  |AAAAAC   |AAA       |           |
| 3   |1.3.1|AAAAACAAA|AAAAAC    |           |
```

So the first Level 2 record Parent Code would be 1.0, first level 3 record Parent Code would be 1.1.1 and so on...

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, first level 3 record Parent Code would be 1.1.

Comment: You can [edit] a question if you want to correct something. Just click the [edit] link at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can self-join the table:

```
select
    t.*,
    p.code
from mytable t
left join mytable p on p.tag = t.parent_tag
```

It is important to use `left join` here, so records without a parent are not evicted from the resultset (unless you do want to do so).

If the same `tag` may appear on different levels, you can make the join condition more specific:

```
select
    t.*,
    p.code
from mytable t
left join mytable p on p.tag = t.parent_tag and p.level = t.level - 1
```

Comment: The Parent TAG field is not a field in the database table. It is derived within the initial query using the LEFT Function show in the original question. We tried this but the Parent Code field ends up all being NULLs:        SELECT T1.[LEVEL], T1.[CODE], T1.[TAG], LEFT(T1.[TAG], LEN(T1.[TAG]) -3) AS [PARENT TAG], T2.[Code] AS [PARENT CODE]
 FROM [BDNDETL] AS T1
 LEFT JOIN [BDNDETL] AS T2
 ON LEFT(T1.[TAG], LEN(T1.[TAG]) -3) = T2.[Code]

Comment: Sorry, saw the mistake in our query. The above query works when we updated the following: "LEFT JOIN [BDNDETL] AS T2 ON LEFT(T1.[TAG], LEN(T1.[TAG] - 3) = T2.[TAG]"